# javascript clickable row

Tags: jquery

Im having some trouble with this clickable row using javascript:

http://www.fpmnky.com/test.php

The curser doesnt change to a pointer and if you click the text area of the row it does not go to the link in the code [google.com]

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery( function($) {
            $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() {
                window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
            }).find('a').hover( function() {
                        $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');
                    }, function() {
                        $(this).parents('tr').click( function() {
                            window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
                        });
                    });
            $('tbody tr[data-href]').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

            $('tbody tr[data-href]').hover(function() {
                $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
            });
        });

    </script>

<body>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-href="http://google.com">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> <a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" data-href="http://google.com">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> <a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-href="http://google.com">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> <a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" data-href="http://google.com">
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a> <a href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

It appears to work on jsfiddle just fine though:

http://jsfiddle.net/UN7Pc/5/

What am I missing?

Comment: `cursor: pointer` actually only works on hover — you might as well just set it in CSS.

Comment: `.find('a').hover( function() { $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');`  there is a better way than this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http:Your problem is here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

The location is wrong, if you fix that, your code will work

By the way you can link to jquery through google if you want

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whats the location suppose to be

Comment: at the moment you are trying to get that file from here http://www.fpmnky.com/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js but as you can see, it does not exist, maybe you forgot to upload it!!

Comment: Thats what it was...Im still learning, so thank you for the elementary advise

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the actual problem I notice you're removing the td click event when the user hovers over a real link. The only reason you can be doing this is that the click bubbles up to the tr.

So, instead, bind the td (tr is usually unclickable, it's the td click bubbling up to it that you're catching) and return if it's not the td being clicked.

Your code

```
$('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
}).find('a').hover( function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');
}, function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').click( function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
    });
});
```

Less code

```
$('tbody tr[data-href] td').addClass('clickable').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target!=this) return; 
    window.location = $(this).parent().data('href');
});
```

Also rather than adding CSS in your JS, `cursor:pointer` can only exist on hover (because the pointer isn't on the element at any other time)

```
.clickable {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```